# Extracting compressed folders to external folder(s) using java

Tags: java, jar, zip, filewriter

I have been unable to find this on SO or on google in a comprehensive format.
I am trying to extract a compressed folder (.zip, will be packed into the .jar until I can get this set up) into a directory (found under %appdata%).

What are the classes and methods I would need to do this? I am looking at zipFile and FileWriter to do this, but I don't fully understand how to use the two classes together.

Is there any way to do this? and if so, are there any better (simpler/faster) ways to do this than with zipFile and fileWriter? I am trying to keep file size down as much as possible, without sacrificing efficiency.

Comment: [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) and its subclasses are meant to be used for strings and characters, not binary files like compressed files (zip and jar). So you probably should use streams or something similar to do this.

Comment: As much as the 'duplicate' seems to be, I do not want to include the zips inside of the jar file, but in separate folders on another drive.

Comment: From your own question: "I am trying to extract a compressed folder (.zip, **will be packed into the .jar**) into a directory (found under %appdata%)." Emphasis added, ofc. If this was not your intention, I recommend creating a new question that addresses your question instead of editing this one.

Comment: Good point. But i got autobanned, preventing me from asking said question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `JDK 7` try [`FileSystems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html). Unzipping is very easy something like

```
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), null)) {
      Files.copy.....
}
```